# How do you change the mouse cursor icons in Windows 8(.1)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, cursor, desktop-customization

This used to be something really simple in Windows 7 and prior. You'd drop your .cur and .ani files into `C:\Windows\Cursors` and go to Mouse settings in the Control Panel.

Staying true to form, the metro-era Microsoft seems to have managed to find a way to even make the mouse cursor worse in Windows 8. I can't find any way to change between built-in themes (eg high contrast, large pointers etc) let alone install new ones thanks to replacing a perfectly workable control panel dialog with another mind-numbing 'metro' app for mouse settings.

Is mouse cursor customization even possible any more in Windows 8(.1)? If so, how?

NB: Stardock's CursorFX is not an option as it is yet another part of their ongoing subscription based Object Desktop which they expect you to keep paying for each year but don't support and haven't updated in nearly 2 years. It *kind of* works under Win8x but soooo many bugs, e.g. cursor sits under any kind of pop-up dialog, tooltip, and those damned metro 'apps'.

Comment: http://windowstechies.com/customizing-mouse-pointers-windows-7-8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @crazypotato's link, you have to go through Start > Personalisation and there's a "Change mouse pointers" link on the left.